# Formatting a file into markdown file

Tags: regex, python-3.x, data-structures, split, formatting

Due to necessity I dumped contents of many files into one file which looks like:

```
Filename=A1.cpp
Description=A1 CPP
Listen=/var/run/A1.cpp
Filename=A2.cpp
Description=A2 CPP
Listen=/var/run/A2.cpp
Write=/home/folder/textfile
```

As you might spot, keys repeat themselves. However, there are some exceptions. There may be common keys and different ones.
The goal is something like this:

```
| Filename |   Description  | Listen         |         Write         |
| A1.cpp   |     A1 CPP     | var/run/A1.cpp |           -           |
| A2.cpp   |     A2 CPP     | var/run/A2.cpp | /home/folder/textfile |
```

As you might figure out the output is in md format.
I am considerably new to Python(3).
The questions in my mind can be arranged like;

- How can I split via `=`? (I have tried with regex there were many case I could not handle, e.g. spaces, punctuation, ...)
- How should I store them in order to have the given output? (Dict, 2D-Array; which will always start with Filename)

P.S. For the sake of minimality, I'm showing an oversimplified version of my problem.

Comment: Can we say that each record begins with "Filename="? Are there only these 4 key/value pairs? If there are problems like spaces and punctuation... you haven't shown them so its hard to guess what you want.

Comment: md format...which one? What are the "keys"? What attempts have you made?

Comment: Yes each record starts with Filename=..., the purpose of separation via "=" rely on flexibility for the future uses. Because column names are not only limited to four but also unknown column names will be added. Because of that reason I cannot hard-code the column names which was the previous attempt, though.

Comment: The given format -bar separated- can be turned into a Markdown file. The attempts have been started with hard-coded version, since the keys(column names) dynamically changing on top of common ones I could not handle them via that approach. I tried to divide left and right hand sides via '=' there were way too many exceptions, then I decided to ask; is there a way to handle such case in a smarter way.

Answer (score 0):

Just playing around with regular expressions and `pandas`, this might get you started:

```
import re, pandas as pd

string = """
Filename=A1.cpp
Description=A1 CPP
Listen=/var/run/A1.cpp
Filename=A2.cpp
Description=A2 CPP
Listen=/var/run/A2.cpp
Write=/home/folder/textfile
"""

# regex for your structure
rx = re.compile(r"""
        ^                                     # start of line
        Filename=(?P<filename>.+)[\n\r]       # Filename
        Description=(?P<description>.+)[\n\r] # Description
        Listen=(?P<listen>.+)[\n\r]           # Listen
        (?:Write=(?P<write>.+)[\n\r])?        # Write, optional
        """, re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

# column labels
labels = ['Filename', 'Description', 'Listen', 'Write']
rows = [match.groups() for match in rx.finditer(string)]

# formatter for the columns
mdformat = lambda x: '{} |'.format(x)

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=labels)
df.fillna('-', inplace = True)

# print it out using the mdformat function
print(df.to_string(index=False, header = False,
        formatters={'Filename': mdformat, 'Description': mdformat, 
                    'Listen': mdformat, 'Write': mdformat}))
```

---

This yields

```
A1.cpp |  A1 CPP |  /var/run/A1.cpp |                      - |
A2.cpp |  A2 CPP |  /var/run/A2.cpp |  /home/folder/textfile |
```

---

So basically the code scans your string, puts the result into a list and creates a `pandas` dataframe from it. This is printed out using a formatter function.